# Common CRC file formats

Tags: file-format, crc

Are there any common (or even standardized) file formats that are used to store CRC parameter sets (i.e. polynomial, width, initial value, XOR, etc.)?

It doesn't matter if the format is based on XML, TXT, CSV etc. as long as it commonly used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Ross Williams wrote an [excellent tutorial on CRCs](http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt), in which he defines a canonical set of parameters to define a CRC. Greg Cook took that further and created a [list of known CRCs](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/) that uses those parameters with a standard format and set of names in a single line for each CRC. Here is an example description from that site of what is probably the most common CRC:

```
width=32 poly=0x04c11db7 init=0xffffffff refin=true refout=true xorout=0xffffffff check=0xcbf43926 name="CRC-32"
```

The `check` value is the CRC of the nine-byte string of ASCII characters "123456789".

I wrote the [crcany code](https://github.com/madler/crcany) which reads those parameter lines and computes a CRC using them, applying bit-wise, byte-wise, and word-wise algorithms. Included with crcany is crcgen, which generates C code for any CRC.

This parameter set does not tell you how to put the CRC in a byte stream. That is a convention of the data format, not the CRC itself. So you are left having to say whether the bytes of the CRC word are to be stored in the stream in little-endian or big-endian order, as well as where they go and what the CRC is computed over.